# List rows from table and associate information from another with MySQL

Tags: mysql

Supposing I've 3 SQL tables like this:

Table fruits:

```
|----------|------------|
| fruit_id | fruit_name |
|----------|------------|
|        1 |     Banana |
|        2 |      Apple |
|        3 |       Pear |
|----------|------------|
```

Table colors:

```
|----------|------------|
| color_id | color_name |
|----------|------------|
|       91 |     Yellow |
|       92 |      Green |
|       93 |        Red |
|----------|------------|
```

Table associatives:

```
|----------|----------|
| fruit_id | color_id |
|----------|----------|
|        1 |       91 |
|        1 |       92 |
|        2 |       91 |
|        2 |       92 |
|        2 |       93 |
|        3 |       93 |
|----------|----------|
```

How can I list the fruits and the associates colors like this:

```
|----------|----------|
| fruit_id | color_id |
|----------|----------|
|        1 |    91,92 |
|        2 | 91,92,93 |
|        3 |       93 |
|----------|----------|
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT 
    fruit_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(color_id, "0")) AS color_id
FROM fruits
JOIN associatives
LEFT JOIN colors
    ON FIND_IN_SET(fruit_id, color_id)
GROUP BY fruit_id
```

Comment: Why  you need LEFT JOIN? Are there fruits without colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a `LEFT JOIN` if you have fruits without colors. But your sample data doesn't show that. Anyway I adapt the sample from @Hackerman to include another fruit to show how to handle that case

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e5809/1)**

```
select f.fruit_id, GROUP_CONCAT( COALESCE (a.color_id, 0) ) as color_id 
from fruits f
left join associatives a
  ON f.fruit_id = a.fruit_id
group by f.fruit_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to query your `associates` table in order to get the desired result:

```
 select fruit_id, GROUP_CONCAT(color_id) as color_id 
 from associatives
 group by fruit_id
```

> **Demo:** 
>   <kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b3e6/1)</kbd>